# Parsing XML DOM with ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xmldom

i'm fairly new at web development, especially so with ASP.NET (but i am a CS major, so that helps).  i have done some web dev before but somebody else could always help with anything i didn't understand.

anyways, i'm trying to link to a site passing in the name of the link as a query string which will then be used to load the proper XML document and parse it.  the problem i've encountered is that i have only parsed XML with javascript, which has been fine for practicing, but the problem is that the query string is being read server-side and the javascript is run client side.

here is what i have so far (obviously not working):

```
@{Layout="/Shared/GuideLayout.cshtml";}

<!-- I like to keep layouts separate from variables, not sure if this is proper -->
@{string name = Request.QueryString["name"];}

<script type="text/javascript">

    var aname = @name;
    document.write(aname);
    xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("/XML/" + aname + ".xml");
    document.write(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue));
</script>

@name
```

so as you can see, i get the query string, which works just fine, the problem is that the title is not printed anywhere (which is as expected).  here is the code for loadXMLDoc:

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
    {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }

        else
        {
            xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
        xhttp.send();
        return xhttp.responseXML;
    }
```

i have tried using the "runat="server"" attribute for the script but that did not do anything.  i have parsed this XML document before so i know the code works, the problem is that i am not sure how to implement this given my current knowledge.

when i googled this, somebody had suggested creating a page that contained the javascript and then passing it into a function i defined there, the problem is that i still do not know how to get the query string from ASP.NET into the javascript to be passed in.  i've also seen some pages with a <%@ Page Language=”C#” %> tag at the top but this appears to be outdated because i receive errors when putting this tag in.

i am using microsoft webmatrix to create this website and pretty much learned everything i know was from google and W3School's article on ASP.NET for webpages (i do not need to make use of webforms and MVC architecture is not necessary for this project).  thanks for any help.